# Error when debugging Pycharm 'python_implementation'

Tags: python, pycharm, virtualenv, python-3.6

I am using PyCharm along with Python 3.6 from a virtual environment and when debugging (not when running) a script I get the following error:

```
/home/developer/master/bin/python3 /snap/pycharm-community/155/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py --multiproc --qt-support=auto --client 127.0.0.1 --port 34977 --file /home/developer/motionplanningthesishector/Planner/control/studywolf_control/controllers/ilqr_truck.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/snap/pycharm-community/155/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 20, in <module>
    from _pydevd_bundle.pydevd_constants import IS_JYTH_LESS25, IS_PYCHARM, get_thread_id, get_current_thread_id, \
  File "/snap/pycharm-community/155/helpers/pydev/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_constants.py", line 183, in <module>
    from _pydev_imps._pydev_saved_modules import thread
  File "/snap/pycharm-community/155/helpers/pydev/_pydev_imps/_pydev_saved_modules.py", line 22, in <module>
    import xmlrpc.server as _pydev_SimpleXMLRPCServer
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/xmlrpc/server.py", line 115, in <module>
    import pydoc
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/pydoc.py", line 67, in <module>
    import platform
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/platform.py", line 116, in <module>
    import sys, os, re, subprocess
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 50, in <module>
    import signal
  File "/home/developer/motionplanningthesishector/Planner/control/studywolf_control/controllers/signal.py", line 18, in <module>
    import numpy as np
  File "/home/developer/master/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 142, in <module>
    from . import core
  File "/home/developer/master/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 100, in <module>
    from . import _internal
  File "/home/developer/master/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/_internal.py", line 20, in <module>
    IS_PYPY = platform.python_implementation() == 'PyPy'
AttributeError: module 'platform' has no attribute 'python_implementation'
```

My Python installation seems correct because I can debug other files that I had created in the past but cannot debug any script newly created.

Answer (score 2):

I see a problem in this part of the traceback:

```
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 50, in <module>
    import signal
```

Module `subprocess` [imports `signal`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/5c4568a05a0a62b5947c55f68f9f2ecfb90a4f12/Lib/subprocess.py#L50). It must be [this one](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/5c4568a05a0a62b5947c55f68f9f2ecfb90a4f12/Lib/signal.py); in your directory structure it must be `/usr/lib/python3.6/signal.py`. But instead it tries

```
  File "/home/developer/motionplanningthesishector/Planner/control/studywolf_control/controllers/signal.py", line 18, in <module>
```

I suspect the problem is in wrong `sys.path` or `$PYTHONPATH`.

Comment: Good catch. Issue could also be a wrong working directory which gives the import preference above the libraries.

Comment: I understand, is confusing a name from CPython module with a script in my project, what can I do if I don't want to change the name of the script in the project? (As it is a cloned repo)

Comment: If it's a script or a top-level module there is no other way but to rename it. Scripts or user-created top-level modules or packages must not overshadow Python modules/packages. Never name you scripts, modules or packages `email`, `test`, etc. If it's not a top-level module — remove its directory from `$PYTHONPATH`.